# Change php upload tmp file permission. Clamav deamon cant access

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm currently developing a new website where a lot of files will be uploaded and downloaded.

When a file is uploaded to the server clamav will start a virus scan on the tmp file before it will be moved to the http server. Everything works great except when i use clamscan and it seems like clamav needs to upload the hole virus database before the scan starts every time and this stress my cpu to 50% for maybe 10 - 20 seconds.

This seem to be a big problem because if two users upload files at the same time to my website it will probably be very slow.

So I installed clamav deamon because it runs in the background and already have the virus database loaded so a lot of time and cpu power can be saved. But to the problem...

When i use clamdscan (clamav deamon) it cant access any of the tmp files that's uploaded with the php script. It only works when i use clamscan. This is probably because clamdscan is running in the background and uses some very strict user permissions.

But how can i solve this? Can i change the tmp php upload file permission from 0600 to 0644? Is that safe? Or should i change permission for clamav deamon?

I don't really know how to do this and if someone know and what to shear I'm very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `--fdpass` as an option to clamdscan.

I had the exact same issue and it worked for me.

> --fdpass
> Pass the file descriptor permissions to clamd. This is useful if clamd is running as a different user as it is faster than streaming the file to clamd. Only available if connected to clamd via local(unix) socket.

Source: https://linux.die.net/man/1/clamdscan